# capcha for nodejs/express

Tags: node.js, express, recaptcha

I need to make capcha on my nodejs/express application. So I have the following questions:

1. Are there any capcha projects for nodejs instead [nodejs-recaptcha](https://github.com/aldipower/nodejs-recaptcha) (the last commit was one year ago)?
2. I'm interesting in "non standart" capcha like [picapcha](http://picatcha.com/captcha/) so it would be prefer to make this one in my project but unfortunaly it has no nodejs support yet. Are there the same project for nodejs/express personaly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides nodejs-recaptcha there is not much to choose from.

1. A quick search using [toolbox.no.de for example](http://toolbox.no.de/search?q=captcha) gave me almost no results.
2. I don't think it should be that hard to write the module yourself that interacst with picapcha.